# Running Thread by calling start() and run(), what is the difference?

Tags: java, multithreading

It may be a basic question, i was confused with this,

in one file i have like this :

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //stuffs
    }
}
```

now in another file i have this :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread obj = new MyThread();

        //now cases where i got confused
        //case 1
        obj.start();   //it makes the run() method run
        //case 2
        obj.run();     //it is also making run() method run
    }
}
```

so in above what is the difference between two cases, is it case 1 is creating a new thread and case 2 is not creating a thread ? that's my guess...hope for better answer SO guys.Thanks

Comment: There is a nice link which covers thread fundamentals : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: @rai.skumar thanks for the link, but that is on concrrency, not what i asked here.

Comment: What "better answer" were you hoping for?  Here's the short answer:  start() is the method that the library provides for you to call when you want to start a thread.  run() is the method that _you_ provide for the library to call, that determines what the thread will do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) runs the code in `run()` in a new thread.  Calling `run()` directly does not execute `run()` in a new thread, but rather the thread `run()` was called from.

If you call `run()` directly, you're not threading.  Calling `run()` directly will block until whatever code in `run()` completes.  `start()` creates a new thread, and since the code in `run` is running in that new thread, `start()` returns immediately.  (Well, technically not immediately, but rather after it's done creating the new thread and kicking it off.)

Also, you should be [implementing runnable, not extending thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread).

Answer (score 2):

Calling start() will create a new execution thread, and then the run() will be executed in the newly created thread

where as directly calling run() will execute the code in the current thread

Answer (score 2):

- run() method after calling start() : this is executed by your thread which is created by you, it is allocated processor to run independently.
- run() method called by you : executed from your calling thread.

Answer (score 2):

the simple answer to your question is this:

run(): runs the code in the run() method, **blocking until it's complete**

start(): **returns immediately (without blocking)** and another thread runs the code in the run() method

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) *starts* the thread. It does the underlying work to create and launch the new thread, and then calls `run` on that new thread.

Calling `run` just calls the [`run`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) method, *on the current thread*. You never call `run` directly, use `start`.

Answer (score 1):

In one line directly calling `run()` is ***synchronous*** (your code will block until run() returns) and calling `start()` (your code will not wait for run to complete as it is called in other thread `obj`) is ***asynchronous***.

When you directly use `start()` method, then the thread will run once using the Runnable instance you provided to it and then the thread will be unusable.

But to leverage the Thread Pooling and Scheduling capabilities that are inbuilt in Java, extending a Runnable or Callable is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

start() starts the thread. run() just runs the code, in the current thread.